# how transform a txt files to a scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Int]

Tags: scala, dictionary, mapping

I spent a lot of time and I don't get the way to transform the following txt to a scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Int]

```
"Becky Smith",12
"John Smith",42
"John",27
"Jones",36
"Matt Jones",48
"Matthew",21
"Rebecca",3
"Sarah Jones",18
"Sarah",33
"Smith",30
-73ef638e:15c66949809:-7ffc,45
-73ef638e:15c66949809:-7ffd,34
-73ef638e:15c66949809:-7ffe,9
-73ef638e:15c66949809:-7fff,39
http://somewhere/JohnSmith/,40
http://somewhere/MattJones/,46
http://somewhere/RebeccaSmith/,10
http://somewhere/SarahJones/,16
http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#FN,47
http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#Family,35
http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#Given,32
http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#N,44
```

First I try to read the file in the normal way, but I couldnt to add the lines to the Map[String,Int], Do you have some idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **Scala**, you don't need a **mutable map** to append, you can [map](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/Iterator.html#map[B](f:A=>B):Iterator[B]) to a **new collection** that contains `tuple` type(like below: `(t(0), t(1).toInt)`), and finally [toMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/Iterator.html#toMap[T,U]:scala.collection.Map[T,U]) to convert this `collection` to **Map**, maybe like:

```
Source.fromFile(new File("test.txt")).getLines().map(_.split(",")).map(t => (t(0), t(1).toInt)).toMap
```

Comment: Thank you, but now I have another question, if I have an String like this " "Bass, Keyboards, Vocals",48231 the compiler detects and error, how can save "Bass, Keyboards, Vocals" as String ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `split` the `input text` with `,` and then convert the `splitted text` into `mutable hashmap`. The result would be a collection of `hashmaps` i.e. `rdd of hashmaps`

The code is as below

```
val data = sc.textFile("path to your text file")

val rddMaps = data.map(line => line.split(",")).map(array => collection.mutable.HashMap[String, Int](array(0)->array(1).toInt))
```